# Nvidia Cuda Installation Package Conflicts

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

I am trying to install Cuda and have been following the Cuda docs but I am at the part where I need to install the cuda package so I run `sudo apt-get install cuda`.

Which outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (12.2.2-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (>= 535.104.12) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.104.12-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-84-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic nvidia-firmware-535-server-535.104.12
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 61.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 245994 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.104.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-535 (535.104.12-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.104.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/nvidia/535.104.12/gsp_ga10x.bin', which is also in package nvidia-firmware-535-server-535.104.12 535.104.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.104.12-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It appears that there are some dependency conflicts but I am unsure how to resolve these as the nvidia-firmware package seems important for interfacing with GPU but also need the nvidia common package for cuda.

I am on the following system:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 6.5.5-060505-generic
- GPU: NVIDIA A100 PCIe 40GB
- Nvidia driver 535

Comment: You have a kernel (6.5.5) newer than one from the standard repos, an Nvidia driver (535.04.12) older than from the standard repos, so you can expect some issues upon update, but CUDA should depend upon neither. Don't use the package manager to install cuda, but use the Nvidia .run script, refusing Nvidia driver updates and override the bin/lib location to be the cuda install location (not the default system areas). See answers 1077061 and 1219761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an overwrite flag from apt: this might work:

apt --fix-broken install -o DPkg::options::="--force-overwrite"

Best of luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This only gave me the same error OP received..

Comment: This worked for me and got my computer booting to desktop again. Thanks man.